# ImportError but software present in conda list

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror, mpi4py

I have installed mpi4py in local anaconda environment. On running the following command, the package does show as installed via pip.

conda list -n myEnvPy36 mpi4py

When I try to import it in the python script, there is an Import error saying No module named mpi4py. The anaconda environment is active while running the script.

Can someone please help me on how to rectify this issue?

Comment: are you executing the code in the same terminal where the environment is active?

Comment: yes, I am running the code in the same terminal

Comment: can you add screenshots to better understand your situation?